# SwiftUI / Combine : Listening array items value change

Tags: swift, swiftui, reactive, combine

I want to display multiple text fields, representing scores of each part of a match.

Example : For a volleyball match, we have 25/20, 25/22, 25/23. The global score is 3/0.

The global components architecture :

```
>> ParentComponent
    >> MainComponent
        >> X TextFieldsComponent (2 text fields, home/visitor score)
```

The lowest component, TextFieldsComponent, contains basic bindings :

```
struct TextFieldsComponent: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        let id: String
        @Published var firstScore: String
        @Published var secondScore: String

        var description: String {
            "\(firstScore) \(secondScore)"
        }

        init(id: String, firstScore: String = .empty, secondScore: String = .empty) {
            self.id = id
            self.firstScore = firstScore
            self.secondScore = secondScore
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Dom.", text: $model.firstScore)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            TextField("Ext.", text: $model.secondScore)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        }
    }
}
```

**The parent component needs to show the total score of all parts of the match. And I wanted to try a Combine binding/stream to get the total score.**

I tried multiple solutions and I ended up with this non-working code (the reduce seems to not be take all the elements of the array but internally stores a previous result) :

```
struct MainComponent: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    @ObservedObject private var totalScoreModel: TotalScoreModel

    class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var scores: [TextFieldsComponent.Model]

        init(scores: [TextFieldsComponent.Model] = [TextFieldsComponent.Model(id: "main")]) {
            self.scores = scores
        }
    }

    private final class TotalScoreModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var totalScore: String = ""
        private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

        init(publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>) {
            cancellable = publisher.print().sink {
                self.totalScore = $0
            }
        }
    }

    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        totalScoreModel = TotalScoreModel(
            publisher: Publishers.MergeMany(
                model.scores.map {
                    Publishers.CombineLatest($0.$firstScore, $0.$secondScore)
                        .map { ($0.0, $0.1) }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            )
            .reduce((0, 0), { previous, next in
                guard let first = Int(next.0), let second = Int(next.1) else { return previous }
                return (
                    previous.0 + (first == second ? 0 : (first > second ? 1 : 0)),
                    previous.1 + (first == second ? 0 : (first > second ? 0 : 1))
                )
            })
            .map { "[\($0.0)] - [\($0.1)]" }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        )
   }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(totalScoreModel.totalScore)
            ForEach(model.scores) { score in
                TextFieldsComponent(model: score)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm searching for a solution to get an event on each binding change, and merge it in a single stream, to display it in MainComponent.

N/B: The TextFieldsComponent needs to be usable in standalone too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MergeMany` is the correct approach here, as you started out yourself, though I think you overcomplicated things.

If you want to display the total score in the View (and let's say the total score is "owned" by `Model` instead of `TotalScoreModel`, which makes sense since it owns the underlying scores), you'd then need to signal that this model will change when any of the underlying scores will change.

Then you can provide the total score as a computed property, and SwiftUI will read the updated value when it recreates the view.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
   @Published var scores: [TextFieldsComponent.Model]

   var totalScore: (Int, Int) {
      scores.map { ($0.firstScore, $0.secondScore) }
            .reduce((0,0)) { $1.0 > $1.1 ? ( $0.0 + 1, $0.1 ) : ($0.0, $0.1 + 1) }
   }

   private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

   init(scores: [TextFieldsComponent.Model] = [.init(id: "main")]) {
      self.scores = scores
      
      // get the ObservableObjectPublisher publishers
      let observables = scores.map { $0.objectWillChange } 

      // notify that this object will change when any of the scores change
      Publishers.MergeMany(observables)
         .sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send)
         .store(in: &cancellables)
   }
}
```

Then, in the View, you can just use the `Model.totalScore` as usual:

```
@ObservedObject var model: Model

var body: some View {
   Text(model.totalScore)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I didn't thought about merging the ObservableObject publishers.

Comment: @new-dev, using MergeMany is elegant. Do you have any suggestion on observing the changes in the array? I've used a didSet to observe array element changes, i.e. adding new element or remove element. Then clear the old cancellables and re-set with new elements.

Comment: @zrfrank, i'm not sure I understand your question. It's best to post a separate question instead of using comments

Comment: @new-dev, for example, in the OP's example, the `scores` array, we must also observe the add and remove of elements from that array. When add/remove happens, we must clear the previous subscriptions, and remake those subscriptions. In most answers in SO, it is suggested to use `didSet` to perform above actions. And in fact you also need duplicate those in `init` as you suggested. I was looking for a simpler way. And I just figure-out we can use like `$scores.publisher.` in the init alone, without the need of didSet.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using a struct as your model.